# C# Using multidimensional lists to send data in MySql server

Tags: c#, mysql, loops, object, multidimensional-array

I'm blocking a problem for 2 days, so I'd like to have a helping hand x)

I want send data object in my bdd mysql with an object.
Unfortunately Visual studio send me a error in debug output :
Exception levée : 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' dans MySql.Data.dll
Exception levée : 'System.InvalidOperationException' dans MySql.Data.dll

And my database retrieves only the first 3 elements.

```
namespace Test
{
class Console
{


    public class Pronostique
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string numeros { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string journal { get; set; }

        // Constructeur
        public Pronostique()
        {
        }
    }





    public class Bdd
    {

        private MySqlConnection connection;

        // Constructeur
        public Bdd()
        {
            this.InitConnexion();
        }

        // Méthode pour initialiser la connexion
        private void InitConnexion()
        {
            // Création de la chaîne de connexion
            string connectionString = "SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=test2; UID=root; PASSWORD=";
            this.connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }


        //ENVOIE BDD
        public void addPronostique(Pronostique pronostique)
        {
            try
            {
                // Ouverture de la connexion SQL
                this.connection.Open();

                // Création d'une commande SQL en fonction de l'objet connection
                MySqlCommand cmd = this.connection.CreateCommand();

                // Requête SQL
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO pronostique (pro_id, pro_numeros, pro_date, pro_journal) VALUES (NULL, @numero, @date, @journal)";

                // utilisation de l'objet contact passé en paramètre
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numero", pronostique.numeros);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", pronostique.date);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@journal", pronostique.journal);


                // Exécution de la commande SQL
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Fermeture de la connexion
                this.connection.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                // Gestion des erreurs :
                // Possibilité de créer un Logger pour les exceptions SQL reçus
                // Possibilité de créer une méthode avec un booléan en retour pour savoir si le contact à été ajouté correctement.
            }
        }
    }

    //PROGRAMME
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> listeJournaux = new List<string>();
        string[,] listePronosticNumero = new string[66, 34];
        List<string> listeDate = new List<string>();

        [...]

        // ENVOIE BDD
        Bdd bdd = new Bdd();

        for (int y = 0; y <= 56 - 1; y++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                Pronostique pronostique1 = new Pronostique();
                pronostique1.journal = listeJournaux[y];
                pronostique1.numeros = listePronosticNumero[y, i];
                pronostique1.date = listeDate[i];
                bdd.addPronostique(pronostique1);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

But with this code there is no error :

```
for (int y = 0; y <= 56 - 1; y++)
            {
                    Pronostique pronostique1 = new Pronostique();
                    pronostique1.journal = listeJournaux[y];
                    pronostique1.numeros = listePronosticNumero[y, 0];
                    pronostique1.date = listeDate[0];
                    bdd.addPronostique(pronostique1);
            }
```

So I think it's my multiple loop problem, only I can not do otherwise.

Thank you in advance,
Julien.

EDIT :
I have maybe found the problem. When I change listePronosticNumero[y, i] to a string value like "1-2-3" or simple list like listePronostique2[y] it's worked. I've test to transform the list multidimentional to list of list:

```
List<List<string>> resultats = new List<List<string>>();

for (int y = 0; y <= 56 - 1; y++)
            {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
                    {
                        resultats.Add(new List<string>());
                        resultats[y].Add(listePronosticNumero[y,i]);
                        System.Console.WriteLine(resultats[y][i]);
                    }
             }
```

Unfortunately, it's doesn't worked et I've the same problem : I retrieves only 3 object in my bdd MySQL.

Does anyone else have any idea?

EDIT : I've resolve my probleme  thank you flaZer. The new code is :

```
pronostique1.journal = listeJournaux[y];
if (listePronosticNumero[y, i] == null || listePronosticNumero[y, i] == "")
{
     pronostique1.numeros = "0-0-0-0";
}
else
{
     pronostique1.numeros = listePronosticNumero[y, i];
}
bdd.addPronostique(pronostique1);
```

Thank you to all those who answered my question !

Comment: You can start by closing the connection in the finally block

Comment: What happens if you try the other values of `i` in the no error code?

Comment: Does it throw the error in the 1st iteration? If not which iteration does it through the error? What are the values of the parameters in that iteration. For bulk upload to MySQL populating a datatable which same exact typed column then using DataAdatapter.Update(Datatable); is ideal.

Comment: Not familiar with MySql... however.... does it make sense to pass NULL as a parameter for the ID column?  Seems like you should exclude the column completely from either side of the insert statement (i.e., reference 3 columns, not 4).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. NetMage I tested with i = 1 and i = 2 and an error appears:
Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in MySql.Data.dll

And my database takes into account only the 1st object.

Comment: Also, far better to keep the connection open for the entire batch rather than opening and closing it for every insert.  In some cases you may run into using all of the available connections in the pool: it can take a while (milliseconds?) for a connection in the pool to be released for reuse.

Comment: And Yussuf, I'm don't understand sorry. I'm don't very strong in english and in c#. Can you give me an example to use DataAdapter.Update ?

Comment: Ok FLazer thank you i test to open connection before loops and close after

Answer (score 0):

[Yousuf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2619582/yousuf-hossain) is referring to a **DataAdapter** approach similar to the example I provided below. However, not quite sure it will work completely for you since I can't test this using **MySql**.

In any event, we also use below **USING** blocks which takes care of object disposable and also closure of the connection.

The **FILL** method pulls from the database, the schema of the table so that we don't have to manually generate the table definition.

The "1 = 0" is just a hack to get the table schema without returning rows - that may or MAY NOT be your desired intent, but does mirror you example since you aren't checking for existing rows before you **INSERT**.

The **BUILDER** command generates for the **DataAdapter**, the necessary commands to perform the Insert. You'd need it also for an **UPDATE** and **DELETE**. Please see the commented statements below.

And not quite as critical an issue as I raised in my comments, the connection stays open for the entire operation, rather than opening and closing on each of your original inserts.  However, if I were forced to build the individual inserts - which the **DataAdapter** does behind the scenes - I'd be sure to build and implement the within the **USING** block.

The **UPDATE** method carried out the actual calls to the DataBase and depending the changes made to the DataTable, an **Insert**, **Update**, or **Delete** statement will be generated and sent to the Datatase.

I've tested this against **SQL SERVER** and it appears to work fine. Of course I don't know how you populated your **LISTS** so I had to improvise. And again, it's normally not good practice to submit a **NULL** for an **ID** column, even if it auto increments on the database side - but I left it in place per your example (and yes it also worked in **SQL SERVER**, which surprised me!).

One last... even if you can successful convert this to **MySQL**, not sure how the attempt to insert a **NULL** into the **PRO_ID** column will work.  Please of course let us know how it works (or not!) for you.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System;

//PROGRAMME
static void Main1()
{
  // POPULATE THESE BEFORE PROCEEDING!!!

  List<string> listeJournaux = new List<string>();
  string[,] listePronosticNumero = new string[66, 34];
  List<string> listeDate = new List<string>();

  // ENVOIE BDD
  //Bdd bdd = new Bdd();

  using (var conn = new SqlConnection("SERVER=127.0.0.1; DATABASE=test2; UID=root; PASSWORD="))
  {
    conn.Open();
    using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select pro_id, pro_numeros, pro_date, pro_journal from pronostique where 1 = 0", conn))
    {
      using (var pronostique = new DataTable("pronostique"))
      {
        adapter.Fill(pronostique);
        using (var builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
        {
          builder.GetInsertCommand();
          //builder.GetUpdateCommand();// uncomment as needed
          //builder.GetDeleteCommand();// uncomment as needed
          for (int y = 0; y <= 56 - 1; y++)
          {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
            {
              var pronostique1 = new Pronostique() { journal = listeJournaux[y], numeros = listePronosticNumero[y, i], date = listeDate[i] };

              var newRow = pronostique.NewRow();

              newRow["pro_id"] = DBNull.Value;
              newRow["pro_numeros"] = pronostique1.numeros;
              newRow["pro_date"] = pronostique1.date;
              newRow["pro_journal"] = pronostique1.journal;

              pronostique.Rows.Add(newRow);
            }
          }
          adapter.Update(pronostique);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well ever since they killed BLINKY text, BOLD is all I have left to play with :)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response, I've tested this code with MySQL and Visual Studio send me a error : MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : 'Field 'pro_numeros' doesn't have a default value'           And my table pronostique retrieves only the first 3 objects as my old code. I think the probleme is my list PronostiqueNumero because when I change this list with simple list or simple string value, it's worked

Comment: Maybe it is because of the multiple dimension of the list?

Comment: Seems to me, 'pro_numeros' is on the DB side, defined as NOT NULL, and that at least one instance of 'pronostique1.numeros' is NULL.  If this the case, I'd first relax the restraint on the DB side, then try again.  If everything loads successfully, have a look at the data loaded, and look for the row where 'pro_numeros' holds a null value - that should give you a perspective on your source data, and whether your problem derives from it.

Comment: YES thank you very much !! 
Indeed I had to check that what I sent was not null. Perfect now its working ! :D

Comment: Glad to help :) If the overall answer also helped, please +1 and mark as answered... and again, glad I was able to help :)